# Trying to replace Where Amount is greater than limit, replace it with 50% of limit. Number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

Trying to replace where `Amount` is greater than `Limit`, replace it with 50% of `Limit`. However it throwing me the error

> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

```r
Ca_spend$Amount[Ca_spend$Amount > Ca_spend$Limit] <- Ca_spend$Limit/2
```

> Warning message:
> In Ca_spend$Amount[Ca_spend$Amount > Ca_spend$Limit] <- Ca_spend$Limit/2 :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select also the rows where your condition is matched

```
Ca_spend$Amount[Ca_spend$Amount > Ca_spend$Limit] <- Ca_spend$Limit[Ca_spend$Amount > Ca_spend$Limit]/2
```

Otherwise on the left side you've got only the rows where the condition is matched and on the right side you have all rows, that's why it does not work

Answer (score 1):

this should solve it for you.

```
library(dplyr)

Ca_spend <- Ca_spend %>%
  mutate(
    Amount = ifelse(Amount > Limit, Limit/2, Amount)
  )
```

using [dplyr's `mutate` method](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/mutate) you won't have to bother with aligning the two sides of your assignment.
[`ifelse`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/ifelse) will take care of your case-switch (if you ever need more than a binary switch, look into [`case_when`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when)).